# updating a row in sqlite using java

Tags: java, sqlite

i'm working on a college project so security and sql injection isn't my concern here. i'm working on an apartment management system in java and the SQL is sqlite. i created a button that should update a column called wantToSell. when i use Intelliji sql console everything works fine but when i use the following code, nothings happens. here is my codes so far
sell request function:

```
 public static void sellRequest(String userNameFieldi){
        try{
            C.setAutoCommit(false);
            stmt = C.createStatement();
            stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE usersDetails SET wantToSell = 'yes' where house_holder_phoneNumber = '"+userNameFieldi+"';");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Request Submitted");
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Something went wrong");
        }
    }
```

connection function:

```
public static void connect() {
    //Opening connection to Sqlite using JDBC driver
    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        C = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:database.db");
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
        System.exit(0);
    }
    System.out.println("Opened database successfully");
}
```

my button's function:

```
buyOrLeaveBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                connect();
                sellRequest(phonenum);
            }
        });
```

update 1:
this is full class code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.*;

public class userMainPage {
    //normal variables
    public static String name_s_sql;
    public static String is_s_sql;
    public static String homeStatus_s_sql;
    //sql variables
    public static String sql;
    public static Connection C = null;
    public static Statement stmt = null;
    static ResultSet res = null;
    //swing variables
    JPanel userMainPagePanel;
    private JLabel nameLabel;
    private JLabel nameSql;
    private JLabel idSql;
    private JLabel IdLabel;
    private JLabel homeStatusLabel;
    private JLabel homeStatusSql;
    private JButton buyOrLeaveBtn;
    private JButton billHistoryBtn;
    private JButton paymentHistoryBtn;
    private JLabel warningsLabel;
    private JList warningListSql;
    private JButton profileBtn;
    private JButton quitBtn;
    private JLabel watermark;
    public String phonenumber;

    public userMainPage(String phonenum){
        nameLabel.setFont(new Font("calibri", Font.BOLD, 22));
        IdLabel.setFont(new Font("calibri", Font.BOLD, 22));
        warningsLabel.setFont(new Font("calibri", Font.BOLD, 22));
        watermark.setFont(new Font("calibri", Font.BOLD, 22));
        homeStatusLabel.setFont(new Font("calibri", Font.BOLD, 22));
        phonenumber = phonenum;
        connect();
        fillOutForm(phonenum);
        nameSql.setText(name_s_sql);
        idSql.setText(is_s_sql);
        homeStatusSql.setText(homeStatus_s_sql);

        buyOrLeaveBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                connect();
                sellRequest(phonenum);
            }
        });
    }
    public static void connect() {
        //Opening connection to Sqlite using JDBC driver
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            C = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:database.db");
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
            System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println("Opened database successfully");
    }
    public static void fillOutForm(String userNameFieldi){
        //searching in database for username and password
        try{
            C.setAutoCommit(false);
            stmt = C.createStatement();
            res = stmt.executeQuery("select * from usersDetails where house_holder_phoneNumber = '" + userNameFieldi +"';");
            res.next();
            System.out.println("this is working");
            name_s_sql = res.getString("house_holder_name_lastName");
            is_s_sql = String.valueOf(res.getInt("Id"));
            homeStatus_s_sql = res.getString("access_type");
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
        }
    }
    public static void sellRequest(String userNameFieldi){
        //searching in database for username and password
        try{
            C.setAutoCommit(false);
            stmt = C.createStatement();
            sql = "INSERT INTO request_list (Type,PhoneNum,AcOrDc) VALUES (" + "'Sell', '" + userNameFieldi + "', 'wating');";
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
            C.commit();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Request Submitted");
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Something went wrong");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And none of your print statements produce any output?

Comment: You have turned off AutoCommit with `C.setAutoCommit(false);` which means that you need `C.commit();` to save the changes.

Comment: @JANO yeah everything is fine and Joptionpane dialog is created but nothing changes

Comment: @forpas when i use this command i get the following error "org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_BUSY]  The database file is locked (database is locked)"

Comment: Is the database also used by another app?

Comment: @forpas no only this class

Comment: SQLITE_BUSY means that there are other connections to the database that interfere while you are trying to update: https://www.sqlite.org/rescode.html#busy

Comment: @forpas i just updated this post and added the full code. i created a new table and tried inserting data there but still noting works D:

Comment: You have 2 different versions of sellRequest() (one updates and the other inserts) which can't coexist in the same class. Which one do you actually use?

Comment: @forpas doesn't matter. i need both of them but when the first approach wasn't updating, i created the second one just to try the second approach and the second one isn't working as well